# Массив или несколько значений в str_replace

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется следующий код:

```
$kod = !empty($test[1]) ? str_replace('.20.20.0.', '.200.200.0.', $test[1]);
```

Но нужно еще кое-какие циферки поменять, как же это сделать в массиве?

Comment: не хватает третьей части тернарного оператора у вас

Comment: Не могли бы уточнить Ваш ответ?

Comment: вы поясните, вам для нескольких значений надо поменять одну подстроку на другу, или для одной строки несколько значений на другие?

Comment: относительно тернарного оператора, то он имеет вид `условие ? значение-истина : значение-ложь`

Comment: Ну вот допустим я поменял 20.20.0 на 200.200.0, все ок, но нужно еще 30.30.0 поменять на 300.300.0, нужно чтобы это сделался в одном str_replace. Вроде это делается в массиве. Что касается : значение-ложь в курсе, просто забыл написать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам необходимо в строке несколько искомых фраз заменить на другие значения, то `str_replace` может в качестве параметров принимать массивы.

```
$str = "abc";

$result = str_replace(['a','b'], ['x','y'], $str);
print_r($result);
```

результатом будет строка `xyc`.

Comment: Немного не то, что я имею ввиду. Выше написал более подробнее.)

Comment: @Webmaster я ваш комментарий понял так - `str_replace(['20.20.0','30.30.0'], ['200.200.0','300.300.0'], $test[1])`;

Comment: Да, я именно так сделал после Вашей комментарии, но почему-то не сработало, к сожалению.

Comment: @Webmaster видимо есть ошибка где-то еще. Сделайте `print_r([$test[1], $kod])` после замены

Comment: Угу, немного неправильно понял. Теперь заработало, спасибо Вам огромное, Добрый человек. :)